DSolve gives zero-to-the-power term
res1 = Assuming[r > 0 && σ > 0 && δ >= 0 && c > 0 && P >= 0 && γ > 1 && K > 0, 
   FullSimplify@DSolve[{σ^2*P^2*V''[P]/2 + (r - δ)*P*V'[P] - 
        r*V[P] + K*P^γ == 0, V[0] == 0}, V[P], P]];

V1[P_] = res1[[1, 1, 2]];
V1[P]

And the result is:
(1/(2*r*(-1 + γ) - 2*γ*δ + (-1 + γ)*γ*σ^2))*
  (-2*K*P^γ + P^((-2*r + 2*δ + σ^2 - Sqrt[4*(r - δ)^2 + 4*(r + δ)*σ^2 + σ^4])/(2*σ^2))*
    (2* 0^((2*r - 2*δ + (-1 + 2*γ)*σ^2 + Sqrt[4*(r - δ)^2 + 4*(r + δ)*σ^2 + σ^4])/(2*σ^2))*K  + 
     P^(Sqrt[4*(r - δ)^2 + 4*(r + δ)*σ^2 + σ^4]/σ^2)*(2*r*(-1 + γ) - 2*γ*δ + (-1 + γ)*γ*σ^2)*C[1]))

Of course, I could manually remove the 0^ part (see 3rd line of output). But why does Mathematica produce this zero part?

It works perfectly for me. Try to clean the Mathematica memory by going to Menu/Evaluation/QuitKernel/Local. Then again, go to Menu/Evaluation/StartKernel/Local. After that, re-evaluate your code. One more advice: do not use the capital letter K since it is reserved. Use the small k or another letter instead. Have fun!

What happens if the exponent on zero is negative? It's a complicated expression, and if it is positive, Mathematica does not arrive at that conclusion, I guess. Also, it's complicated enough that if you add the assumption that it is positive, FullSimplify does not use it. However, FullSimplify[0^exp, exp > 0] does evaluate to 0. So if you replace the complicated exponent by a variable and assume the variable is positive, the power of zero term is removed.

Actually, it is just DSolve[...] which gives 0^stuff. You can remove all the other code as not needed, including all the assumptions and all the FullSimplify. Simply use DSolve and you will see it.  V 14.1  https://i.sstatic.net/GaRjlgQE.png

@AlexeiBoulbitch  in V 14.1 it does give 0^power, clean kernel and lower case k.

Just an insight why you get 0^{stuff}. It comes from the initial conditions you have. V[0]==0.
sol=DSolveValue[{\[Sigma]^2*P^2*V''[P]/2+(r-\[Delta])*P*V'[P]-r*V[P]+K*P^\[Gamma]==0, V[0]==0},V[P],P]


Replacing the IC with V[p0]==0 now you get as solution  with no 0^{...}
sol=DSolveValue[{\[Sigma]^2*P^2*V''[P]/2+(r-\[Delta])*P*V'[P]-r*V[P]+K*P^\[Gamma]==0, V[p0]==0},V[P],P]


If we remove the IC all together, and try to solve for the constant after that, you see why
sol=DSolveValue[{\[Sigma]^2*P^2*V''[P]/2+(r-\[Delta])*P*V'[P]-r*V[P]+K*P^\[Gamma]==0},V[P],P];
eq=0==Limit[sol,P->0]

Gives

So mathematica could not find the limit. It has to find the limit in order to resolve one of the constant of integration (there are two in the solution).
Instead it seems to just repalced P by zero to solve for C1.
That is why you see the 0^ there. It is from solving for the constant of integration from initial conditions.
Fyi, this is what Maple gives
ode:=sigma^2*P^2*diff(V(P),P$2)/2+(r-delta)*P*diff(V(P),P)-r*V(P)+k*P^gamma=0
dsolve([ode,V(0)=0])


Here is the final solution in plain text
V(P) = -2*k*P^gamma/(gamma^2*sigma^2+(-sigma^2-2*delta+2*r)*gamma-2*r)

You could try to verify this in Mathematica if you want.

After I replaced V[0]==0 by V[p0]==0, I got a more complicated solution with several p0^ parts. I use Edition 14.  I did try Maple before I posted this question, which gave me only a particular solution to the nonhomogeneous ODE, but no general solution to the corresponding homogeneous equation. Mathematica on the other hand includes both parts. Mathematica also handles IC well because the result has only one C; the general solution is in the form of  C1P^{a positive value} +C2P^{a negative value}. Since V[0]=0, Mathematica correctly doesn't include C2*P^{a negative value} in the result.

I get the power of zero in V14.1. As mentioned in my comment, I think the difficulty is in proving the exponent is positive. It's not terribly hard to do, but it is too complicated and Mathematica is not diving deep enough.  Here's a workaround
res1 = Assuming[
   r > 0 && \[Sigma] > 0 && \[Delta] >= 0 && c > 0 && 
    P >= 0 && \[Gamma] > 1 && k > 0,
   FullSimplify[
    DSolve[{\[Sigma]^2*P^2*V''[P]/2 + (r - \[Delta])*P*V'[P] - 
        r*V[P] + k*P^\[Gamma] == 0, V[0] == 0}, V[P], P],
    TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, # /. 
        0^e_ /; (* check exponent positive *)
          Simplify@ Reduce[$Assumptions \[Implies] e > 0] :>
            (FullSimplify[0^exp, exp > 0] /. exp -> e) &}]
   ];
V1[P_] = res1[[1, 1, 2]];
V1[P]
(*
-((2 k P^\[Gamma])/(
  2 r (-1 + \[Gamma]) - 
   2 \[Gamma] \[Delta] + (-1 + \[Gamma]) \[Gamma] \[Sigma]^2)) + 
 P^((-2 r + 2 \[Delta] + \[Sigma]^2 + Sqrt[
   4 (r - \[Delta])^2 + 4 (r + \[Delta]) \[Sigma]^2 + \[Sigma]^4])/(
  2 \[Sigma]^2)) C[1]
*)


Logically you have to exclude that the exponent
$$(2 \gamma -1) \sigma ^2-2 \delta +\sqrt{\frac{(r-\delta )^2}{\sigma ^4}+\frac{\delta +r}{\sigma ^2}+\frac{1}{4}}+2 r$$
is 0, too.
Formally such a term $a(x)^b(x) = e^{\log(a(x)) \ b(x)}$  can be anything, depending on its limit path in parameter space.
If Mathematica refuses to evaluate
 Assuming[expr>0,FullSimplify[0^expr]] -> 0

the reason probably  will be different internal representations of expr in both places. For  a symbol the result is 0.
